# How can I set my custom gas Price and gas Limit?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to set my custom gas and gas Price in sendTransaction method.Currently I set it but when i send the transaction gas fee is showing 0.21 ETH in metamask. How can I solve this?

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
   from: currentAccount,
   to: toAddress,
   value: web3.toWei(value, 'ether'),
   gasPrice: web3.toWei("0.00001" , 'ether'),
   gasLimit: '21000',
   chainId: '0x1'
}
```

Above is my code. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Gas fee = `gasLimit * gasPrice + value`.

In your case, it is `21000 * 0.00001 + value`.

The gas fee that metamask shows you implies that `21000 * 0.00001 + value == 0.21`.

This implies that `value == 0` (i.e., you are  not sending any ether in the transaction).

Subsequently, the gas fee turns out as `21000 * 0.00001 + 0 == 0.21`.

So there is no contradiction between what you set and what metamask shows you.

Comment: HI goodvibration, Thanks for your comment. I tried after setting Gas Fee but I am getting this error. Error:  [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":1428479888420,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf884029f307833386334326531382e363138363137303564363032643637343135376382520894b5ef36bda3c126f4046096635563d47f1517a1738609184e72a0008025a06fc330345fa4424dc4df326bc0f2869adb0c2e8f4cc4c7a32924dabea75fe2c8a05ac8c6c2e40a55a3689df03f3d422dd769e75db33fdf79153726212c4161d27a"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]!

Comment: @AdilKadiyawala: That's a different question. Please post it separately, and if this one has answered your question, then please accept it by clicking on the V next to it.